# Keep getting MongoConnectionException: MongoCursor::rewind(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed

Tags: php, mongodb, nginx, phalcon

I'm using AWS instance and have the following stack configured: nginx, phalcon (1.3.4), MongoDB (server=2.6.6, client=1.5.5), Linux (3.13.0-36-generic #63-Ubuntu) and PHP (5.6).

When developing my app, testing did not reveal any issues. 
After the launch, I started getting this error:

**MongoConnectionException: MongoCursor::rewind(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known**

In the beginning, I narrowed down the problems to unoptimized code. In some cases I was getting an array of elements, looping through and fetching the Mongo object for each of the array's elements. 
I then refactored the code to filter through the entire array inside the app and get Mongo objects on a smaller subset.

My tests also showed that if my array had over 1700 elements, this is where Mongo failed. But after fixing these issues, I am now getting the same exception on a simple find!

```
$users = User::find(array(array('contact.name' => 'Joe')));
```

My Mongo connection settings:

```
$di->set('mongo', function() {
    $mongo = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017,/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock', ["connectTimeoutMS" => 30000]);
    return $mongo->selectDb('test');
}, true);
```

If I would be getting this error right from the getgo, the problem would definitely be in a way how I connect to the DB (hostname cannot be resolved, etc.), but it worked with the same setup before, that's what's confusing!

Tried searching for similar threads, not much luck. Can somebody help?

**Edit**: I tried replacing 'localhost' in the connection string with 127.0.0.1 and it worked for basic commands, but some models in the application still fail

Comment: Could you share the version of mongodb you are running, version of the mongodb driver and type and version of OS?

Comment: I edited the original post with version numbers